# Libre Office Calc keeps removing quotes

Tags: libreoffice, csv

I am opening a `.csv` file using LibreOffice Calc.

However, no matter the format I choose to save the file with after modifying it (either ODF or CSV) for some columns that contained quoted values, the quotes are gone after the save process.

Any suggestions about how to keep the original column formatting?

Comment: could you share your source CSV?

Comment: Look at this [answer from Unix Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/questions/643516/preventing-libreoffice-from-using-smart-quotes-instead-of-dumb-straight)

Answer (score 4):

In the .csv format, one can specify that strings should be quoted. These quotes will *not* show up after you opened the .csv file in Calc.

To make sure that strings are quoted in the .csv file on disk, make sure to check "Quote all text cells" in the "Export Text File" dialog.

If you want to have quotes displayed in your column data (i.e., be part of the actual data), then "escape" the quotes using the same quoting sign. e.g., a string displayed in Calc as `"string with spaces"` will appear in the .csv file as `...,"""string with spaces""",...` if you have chosen the same quote as delimiter in your .csv file.

Comment: Note that in order to see the Export dialog, when you Save As you have to select a new file name.  If you try to Save As and choose you're existing file the dialog will not appear.